# execl + find + -exec: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: c, linux, find, execl

I am trying to run `execlp` with `find ... -exec ...`, and the `find` program consistently tells me:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

What could be wrong? When I run find with these arguments on my shell, it succeeds.

My function calls follow (after looking at related SO threads, I have tried several arrangements of the argmuments):

```
execlp("find","find","/home/me","-exec","/usr/bin/stat", "{}", "\\;",NULL);
execlp("find","find","/home/me","-exec","/usr/bin/stat", "'{}'", "\\;",NULL);
execlp("find","find","/home/me","-exec","/usr/bin/stat", "{}", "';'",NULL);
execlp("find","find","/home/me","-exec","/usr/bin/stat {} \\;",NULL);
```

Comment: execlp == C ? under linux? maybe add those tags.

Comment: @PatrickArtner : added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the command from C, you don't need the `\` before `;`

Using this syntax should work

```
execlp("find","find","/home/me","-exec","/usr/bin/stat", "{}", ";",NULL);
```

When on the shell, `;` marks the end of a command, and has to be escaped. `execlp` doesn't go through the shell to execute a command, it does it immediately.

---

*Edit -- you actually only do one* find  *so this part is not necessary*

Moreover, the `exec` family replaces the current process with the requested command. So only the first `execlp` will be executed.

A solution is to `fork()` for each `find` (one by one, waiting for the child process to end, otherwise the output will be a mix of all results).